# React Render a table from a javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript array of object.

How can I render it in a HTML table?

Basically the object contains the the details of university shuttle trip from different dates and time.

Also if it helps i have retrieved this array of objects from firebase database by filtering from and to dates.

```
[{
    "-LJty9v6G_hGvI0Q9T2y": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "19:44:45",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 2,
        "ReturnTime": "19:45:18",
        "Students": {
            "783524987": {
                "Address": "1020 Westcott St",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:45:05",
                "Name": "nitish",
                "SUID": 783524987,
                "SigninTime": "15:43:35",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "873420987": {
                "Address": "135 Lexington ave.",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:45:11",
                "Name": "kumar",
                "SUID": 873420987,
                "SigninTime": "15:43:53",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    },
    "-LJtzzL5B7-4b0jm4Kq6": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "19:52:56",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 2,
        "ReturnTime": "19:53:14",
        "Students": {
            "541984356": {
                "Address": "512 Westcott St",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:53:05",
                "Name": "rishu",
                "SUID": "541984356",
                "SigninTime": "15:44:14",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "873420987": {
                "Address": "135 Lexington ave.",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:53:14",
                "Name": "kumar",
                "SUID": "873420987",
                "SigninTime": "15:43:53",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    },
    "-LJu-IO5TMOCF9RWdYUZ": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "19:54:30",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 1,
        "ReturnTime": "19:54:36",
        "Students": {
            "719529817": {
                "Address": "445 Columbus Ave",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:54:36",
                "Name": "dilbag",
                "SUID": "719529817",
                "SigninTime": "15:44:35",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    },
    "-LJu1EiQABaUuUHYBov8": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "20:01:20",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 2,
        "ReturnTime": "20:03:06",
        "Students": {
            "873920453": {
                "Address": "1020 Westcott St",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "20:01:34",
                "Name": "diljor",
                "SUID": "873920453",
                "SigninTime": "16:00:54",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "874939393": {
                "Address": "135 Lexington ave.",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "20:02:50",
                "Name": "nitish",
                "SUID": "874939393",
                "SigninTime": "16:00:32",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    }
}, {
    "-LK-eMcyttIyLcIpqLrf": {
        "Date": "08-16-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "02:55:59",
        "DriverName": "Mukul",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 3,
        "ReturnTime": "02:56:11",
        "Students": {
            "619351873": {
                "Address": "141 Concord Pl",
                "Date": "08-15-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "02:56:08",
                "Name": "singhaniya",
                "SUID": "619351873",
                "SigninTime": "16:21:31",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "710936724": {
                "Address": "318 Vincent St",
                "Date": "08-15-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "02:56:06",
                "Name": "dilbag singh",
                "SUID": "710936724",
                "SigninTime": "16:18:08",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "710936728": {
                "Address": "445 Burten St.",
                "Date": "08-15-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "02:56:03",
                "Name": "kumar singh",
                "SUID": "710936728",
                "SigninTime": "16:01:14",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    }
}]
```

i want the object to be transferred to a single html table in following format nested until all trips are accumulated into the table.

Trip1

```
Date:08/14/2018 Departure Time: 19:44:45    Return Time: 19:48:18   No. Of passengers:2 Supervisor: Kumar Singh Driver:rishabh
Passenger Details                   
Name    SUID    SignInTime  Address supervisor  Dropoff Time
Nitish  6489826453  19:40:18    135 Lexington   Kumar Singh 19:45:20
Satish  6489826493  19:40:18    141 Lexington   Kumar Singh 19:46:40
```

Comment: With React you would just use use `map` on the array.  But your array seems in a very strange form, you have an array with 2 objects, and then inside this you have what looks like an array, but it's not, it's an object with multiple guid like keys..  Again odd format, so then you would need to use `Object.entries` on this part, and map that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,.

Just fancied playing around with React, so knocked up a working snippet here.

The trick here is using `Object.entries`, mixed with `Array.map` to render all the tables.

Also just used pureCss to make the tables look a bit nicer.

```js
const data = [{
    "-LJty9v6G_hGvI0Q9T2y": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "19:44:45",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 2,
        "ReturnTime": "19:45:18",
        "Students": {
            "783524987": {
                "Address": "1020 Westcott St",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:45:05",
                "Name": "nitish",
                "SUID": 783524987,
                "SigninTime": "15:43:35",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "873420987": {
                "Address": "135 Lexington ave.",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:45:11",
                "Name": "kumar",
                "SUID": 873420987,
                "SigninTime": "15:43:53",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    },
    "-LJtzzL5B7-4b0jm4Kq6": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "19:52:56",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 2,
        "ReturnTime": "19:53:14",
        "Students": {
            "541984356": {
                "Address": "512 Westcott St",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:53:05",
                "Name": "rishu",
                "SUID": "541984356",
                "SigninTime": "15:44:14",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "873420987": {
                "Address": "135 Lexington ave.",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:53:14",
                "Name": "kumar",
                "SUID": "873420987",
                "SigninTime": "15:43:53",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    },
    "-LJu-IO5TMOCF9RWdYUZ": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "19:54:30",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 1,
        "ReturnTime": "19:54:36",
        "Students": {
            "719529817": {
                "Address": "445 Columbus Ave",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "19:54:36",
                "Name": "dilbag",
                "SUID": "719529817",
                "SigninTime": "15:44:35",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    },
    "-LJu1EiQABaUuUHYBov8": {
        "Date": "08-14-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "20:01:20",
        "DriverName": "Rishabh",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 2,
        "ReturnTime": "20:03:06",
        "Students": {
            "873920453": {
                "Address": "1020 Westcott St",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "20:01:34",
                "Name": "diljor",
                "SUID": "873920453",
                "SigninTime": "16:00:54",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "874939393": {
                "Address": "135 Lexington ave.",
                "Date": "08-14-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "20:02:50",
                "Name": "nitish",
                "SUID": "874939393",
                "SigninTime": "16:00:32",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    }
}, {
    "-LK-eMcyttIyLcIpqLrf": {
        "Date": "08-16-2018",
        "DepartureTime": "02:55:59",
        "DriverName": "Mukul",
        "NumberOfPassengers": 3,
        "ReturnTime": "02:56:11",
        "Students": {
            "619351873": {
                "Address": "141 Concord Pl",
                "Date": "08-15-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "02:56:08",
                "Name": "singhaniya",
                "SUID": "619351873",
                "SigninTime": "16:21:31",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "710936724": {
                "Address": "318 Vincent St",
                "Date": "08-15-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "02:56:06",
                "Name": "dilbag singh",
                "SUID": "710936724",
                "SigninTime": "16:18:08",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            },
            "710936728": {
                "Address": "445 Burten St.",
                "Date": "08-15-2018",
                "DropOffTime": "02:56:03",
                "Name": "kumar singh",
                "SUID": "710936728",
                "SigninTime": "16:01:14",
                "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
            }
        },
        "SupervisorName": "Kumar Singh"
    }
}];



function Student(props) {
  const [key, value] = props.student;
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{value.Name}</td>
      <td>{key}</td>
      <td>{value.SigninTime}</td>
      <td>{value.Address}</td>
      <td>{value.SupervisorName}</td>
      <td>{value.DropOffTime}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}



function Record(props) {
  const [key, value] = props.rec;
  return (
    <div className="record">
      <table className="pure-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th><td>{value.Date}</td>
            <th>Departure<br/>Time:</th><td>{value.DepartureTime}</td>
            <th>Return<br/>Time</th><td>{value.ReturnTime}</td>
            <th>No. Of<br/>passengers</th><td>{value.NumberOfPassengers}</td>
            <th>Supervisor</th><td>{value.SupervisorName}</td>
            <th>Driver</th><td>{value.DriverName}</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
       </table>
       <table className="pure-table pure-table-striped">
         <thead>
          <tr><th colSpan="6">Passenger Details</th></tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>SUID</th>
            <th>SignInTime</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Supervisor</th>
            <th>Dropoff Time</th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           {Object.entries(value.Students).map(s => (
             <Student key={s[0]} student={s}/>
           ))}
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
  );
}

console.log(React.Fragment);

ReactDOM.render(
  (<React.Fragment>
    {
      data.map(
        d => Object.entries(d).map(d => <Record key={d[0]} rec={d}/>)
      )
    }
  </React.Fragment>),
  document.getElementById("mount")
);
```

```css
#mount {
  width: 1200px;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
.record {
  margin: 10px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="mount">
</div>
```